# Content disappear if you come from an indirect link

Tags: video, hyperlink

Since I don't know what exactly this property is, so I will explain it step by step, hopefully someone could help me to make it.

This is a link 
https://cera.video/series-fbi-episode-3-season-1-s01e03-mosalsal-video-motarjam-translated-download-watch-video.html

- Press right click on the (playing Video Icon) and choose OPEN LINK IN NEW TAB + press again and choose OPEN LINK IN NEW PRIVATE TAB.
- In the first tab: You would see an article and inside it there is a video player and it has many options to play the video in different servers.
- In the private tab: You would see the same article but WITHOUT the video player and its options!.

That means, if you want to see the video you must click on the (playing video icon) that's in the previous page, otherwise you would see the article without the video.

BTW, I saw many videos sites have the same property.

Comment: it is because it is a fake website trying to sell you stuff and will never show you a video. if you're interested in the workings, I suggest you start by learning HTML. like here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: I don't think so. It's just a property to tell the browser TO NOT show the videos if the user didn't came from the previous page. there's nothing to be sold in that site, it's just a video site.